# Maximum number of ufo that can visit any planet

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> Consider an infinite alien 2d world consisting of infinite planet, so that distance between any two planets is not same. Now at some point of time, a ufo leaves each planet and goes to planet nearest to it. *Only one ufo leaves each planet.* Find the maximum number of ufo that can land on any planet.

For this question, I found the critical condition of a hexagon inscribed inside a circle with centre as planet P. Now, in this case all distances are equal. So by intuition, it appears that maximum no of ufo that can land on P should be 5 planets $p_i$, each lying so as to satisfy constraints.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: A reasoning appealing to intuition cannot be rigorous.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but say planet $a$ is closest to planet $b$, if there are $k$ ufos on planet $b$ then each will travel to planet $a$. But honestly I'm not sure if you are even allowing for multiple ufos.

Comment: @T.Ford Only one ufo leaves each planet. This action happens only once. We need to count maximum ufo that have come

Comment: @jeaa Do you mean that: 1) exactly one ufo starts from a given planet? 2) when a ufo moves to another planet, it will not move again to another planet?

Comment: Oh I see, so one ufo on each planet. Then the action occurs. good question

Comment: You've provided an *intuition* for why there can be no more than $5$ ufo's on any planet. This can be made into a rigorous argument, yielding an *upper bound* of $5$ ufo's on any planet. It then remains to prove that this upper bound can in fact be achieved.

Comment: Hint: in a triangle, the side opposite an angle less than $60^\circ$ cannot be largest.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition seems correct, but as it is written your argument is far from rigorous. Let me get you started on a (thoroughly) rigorous argument:

Consider a configuration of planets where the maximum number of UFO's on one planet is achieved. Let $M$ be a planet with the maximum number of UFO's. Let $P_1$ be the nearest planet from which a UFO came to $M$ (clearly the maximum is at least $1$). Then all other planets from which the UFO's on $M$ came are closer to $M$ than to $P_1$, but farther from $M$ than $P_1$. That is, they are *outside* the blue region in the image below:

[image]

Now let $P_2$ be a second planet from which a UFO came to $M$. Then the angle $\angle P_1MP_2$ is greater than...

Comment: ... 60 degrees!

Comment: Great! Can you complete the argument from here?